# React alternative which uses JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I like the JSX syntax in React and want to know if there is any other JavaScript framework that uses JSX.

I am looking for a ReactJs alternative supporting JSX.

Comment: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/ - you can use jsx in anything with this babel plugin :)

Comment: Vue.js supports JSX: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preact** is lightweight 3kb alternative of React, if you like it small and fast, then use it.

https://github.com/developit/preact

As @Pistachio mentioned earlier, you can use jsx with whatever you like just adding transform-react-jsx to your project and setting the `pragma` function to your preferred in your `.babelrc` file.

Preact uses `hyperscript` which is pretty good for performing the operation you want https://github.com/hyperhype/hyperscript